# UFT 12.2 relative paths are becoming fixed after they resolve once

Tags: qtp

I am trying to implement relative pathing for my UFT scripts.  This is something that I've done before in the past, however I am having trouble now.  I set the relative pathing using the Tools->Folders pane, and after setting the path resolves to the full path (functions and object repositories are found as expected)

Entered:  '..\..\Functions'

Resolved to: 'C:\blah\blah\UFTScripts\Functions'
(this part seems correct)

The issue begins whenever I open scripts on a different network drive.  On both drives we have the same folder structure setup so the same relative paths should work on both drives, but when I look at the folders pane the resolved paths from the first drive are still showing.

Opened script @ I:\blah\blah\UFTScripts\Functions

Folder pane showing: C:\blah\blah\UFTScripts\Functions

It seems to me that once the relative paths resolve once, they are fixed to that path.  It was my understanding that relative paths should resolve every time that a script is opened.

Any advice or guidance to get UFT to resolve to the script path every time would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a bug. Good luck reporting this one.

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  I've gotten HP to acknowledge this issue via screen share, so we will see what comes of it...

Comment: Just to update, HP has provided us .dll fixes for the issue.  I guess if anyone else needs this fix then contact your support reps.

Comment: Thanks. Now please create an answer, accept it, and let this question disappear from the list of unanswered questions ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HP acknowledged the issue and provided several modified dll's to fix it.